# MySQL optimized performance for two large tables with same index

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have two tables with huge amount of data in them (~1.8mil in the main one, ~1.2mil in the secondary one), as follows:

subscriber_table (id, name, email, country, account_status, ...)
subscriber_payment_table (id, subscriber_id, payment_type, payment_credential)

My end goal is having a table, containing all the users and their payment tables (null if non existing), up to **yesterday**, and with account_status = 1 (active)

Mot all subscribers have a corresponding subscriber_payment, so using an INNER JOIN isn't a viable option, and using a LEFT JOIN has me end up with SQL timing out my query after 2 hrs after much processing effort.

```
SELECT 
    `subscribers`.`id` AS `id`,
    `subscribers`.`email` AS `email`,
    `subscribers`.`name` AS `name`,
    `subscribers`.`geoloc_country` AS `country`,

    `subscribers_payment`.`payment_type` AS `paymentType`,
    `subscribers_payment`.`payment_credential` AS `paymentCredential`

    `subscribers`.`create_datetime` AS `createdAt`
FROM
    `subscribers`
LEFT JOIN 
    `subscribers_payment` ON (`subscribers_payment`.`subscriberId` = `subscribers`.`id`)
WHERE
    `subscribers`.`account_status` = 1
    AND DATE_FORMAT(CAST(`subscribers`.`create_datetime` AS DATE), '%Y-%m-%d') < curdate())
```

As mentioned, this query takes too much time and ends up timing out and not working. 
I've also considered having a UNION, between "All the Subscribers" and "Subscribers with Payment".

```
(
SELECT 
    `subscribers`.`id` AS `id`,
    `subscribers`.`email` AS `email`,
    `subscribers`.`name` AS `name`,
    `subscribers`.`geoloc_country` AS `country`,

    null AS `paymentType`,
    null AS `paymentCredential`

    `subscribers`.`create_datetime` AS `createdAt`
FROM
    `subscribers`
WHERE
    `subscribers`.`account_status` = 1
    AND DATE_FORMAT(CAST(`subscribers`.`create_datetime` AS DATE), '%Y-%m-%d') < curdate()))
UNION
(
SELECT 
    `subscribers`.`id` AS `id`,
    `subscribers`.`email` AS `email`,
    `subscribers`.`name` AS `name`,
    `subscribers`.`geoloc_country` AS `country`,

    `subscribers_payment`.`payment_type` AS `paymentType`,
    `subscribers_payment`.`payment_credential` AS `paymentCredential`

    `subscribers`.`create_datetime` AS `createdAt`
FROM
    `subscribers`
INNERJOIN 
    `subscribers_payment` ON (`subscribers_payment`.`subscriberId` = `subscribers`.`id`)
WHERE
    `subscribers`.`account_status` = 1
    AND DATE_FORMAT(CAST(`subscribers`.`create_datetime` AS DATE), '%Y-%m-%d') < curdate()))
```

The problem with that current implementation is that I'm getting duplicate queries (I'm using a UNION but it's not grouping my results together and removing non-distinct values, that's because I have a different value in the `paymentType` and `paymentCredential` columns)

This query runs in about ~2mins, so this is more feasible for me. I just need to eliminate duplicate records.. unless there's a wiser option here

Disclaimer: we're using MyISAM tables, so having foreign keys to speed up the queries is a no-go.

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
SELECT  . . . 
FROM subscribers s LEFT JOIN
     subscribers_payment sp
     ON sp.subscriberId = s.id
WHERE s.account_status = 1 AND
      s.create_datetime < curdate();
```

Then, you want an index on `subscribers(account_status, create_datetime, id)` and on `subscribers_payment(subscriberId)`.

I am guessing that the index on `subscriber_payment` is missing, which explains the performance problems.

Notes:

- Use table aliases -- they make the query easier to write and read.
- There should be no need to convert a `datetime` to a string for comparison purposes.
- There is no need to use backticks for all identifiers.  They just make the query harder to write and read.

Comment: Hi, I have indexes on all of the fields you mentioned, and yet my query still takes an abnormal amount of time to be processed (AKA so long that it times out). I also removed the DATE_FORMAT(CAST()) part, to no result. Thank you for the other notes. I personally prefer it like you said, I'd do the same if it was my personal project, howeverI'm just following the company's current architecture for code consistency

Comment: @PatrickYounes . . . Two indexes, with the columns in the order that is specified.  Those are the indexes you have?